# Using a search button in excel how do I make the search by entering any key word in the search cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub searchdata()

Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow
   If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 2) = Sheet2.Range("B3") Then
     Sheet2.Range("A11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1)
     Sheet2.Range("B11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 2)
     count = count + 1
  End If

  If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = Sheet2.Range("B3") Then
     Sheet2.Range("A11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1)
     Sheet2.Range("C11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3)
     count = count + 1
  End If
Next x

If count = 0 Then
   Set ws = Worksheets("sheet3")
   erow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   Sheet2.Range("A11:C11").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please use code tags in future. And don't just post a lot of code, explain your question and the problem with the code you have.

Comment: Voting to close as no idea what you're after.  Based on the word "search" in the title - you may want to look at the VBA command `FIND`.

Answer (score 0):

The bits

```
Sheet2.Range("A11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1)
Sheet2.Range("C11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 2)
Sheet2.Range("C11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3)
```

are inside the loop, so they continually get over-written each time round. No idea what you want to do, but this looks pointless.